# thead is not shown in medium viewport

Tags: html, css

I have two tables on the page http://fadendaten.herokuapp.com/cart

both tables with thead.

```
            <table class="stack articles">
              <thead>
                <tr>
                  <th class="article" colspan="2">Artikel</th>
                  <th class="size">Grösse</th>
                  <th class="amount">Menge</th>
                  <th class="price">Preis</th>
                  <th class="total">Gesamtpreis</th>
                </tr>
              </thead>
              <tbody>
                ....
```

But strangely the thead is not visible in the medium viewport 640px-1024px.

I suppose this is caused by a media query but i can't find the location in the css where thead is make invisible.

Can someone help me out?

Comment: Search your stylesheet for `table.stack thead`. It is being hidden in the `@media screen and (max-width: 63.9375em)` media query.

Comment: ^ in this file `/assets/application-e3bead3192d31fb80d1e7582d53fd8112193e6bc7243cbe8d0aaee92ac5a5b68.css`

Comment: Thanks guys, i found it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @turnip and @BenG i found the location:

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 40em) and (max-width: 63.9375em) {
  table.stack thead {
    display: inline;
  }
}
```